# PlayAtTime Issue playing multiple audio files

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, file

All
I have two audio files (caf) which I want to my audioplayer play one after the other. Below is the code I am using

```
AVAudioPlayer *lSoundPlayer;
AVAudioPlayer *lSoundPlayer1;


NSTimeInterval timedelay = 2;

[lSoundPlayer play];
[lSoundPlayer1 playAtTime:timedelay];
```

When I compile I am getting a warning that the AVaudio player might not respond. When I try to execute I am getting exception. Can someone please help

Comment: In future please (a) format your code and (b) specify at minimum the platform/OS/tools you are talking about - I am assuming iOS here and have added a tag, but it could just as easily be Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a message to an object which is neither allocated nor it is initialized.

I suggest you have a look at the class reference and ask again if you have any further questions: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I got this working with audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying. I am very new to programming overall and understanding the documents itself is kind of a challenge for me.

Comment: With a name like "Newbie"?